# Set of multivarible expressions to be re-expressed a single variable

Tags: equation-solving, variable-definitions, system-variables

I have a set of expression such as $\frac{3x+y-z}{6x}$ and $\frac{3 x-y+z}{12 x}$, which can easily get re-expressed as $p$ and $(1-p)/2$, where $p=\frac{3x+y-z}{6x}$, but is there a way to find this $p$, not manually? That is: how do I find a $p$ such that every expression can be expressed solely as a function of $p$ in Mathematica? (I *know* it is true to find such a $p$ for a given set, I just am not able to computationally find it)

Comment: (1) If such a relation exists, it can be found using a Groebner basis that eliminates `x,y,z` as below. `In[110]:= 
polys = {p1 - ((3*x + y - z)/(6*x)), p2 - ((3*x - y + z)/(12*x))};
GroebnerBasis[polys, {p1, p2}, {x, y, z}]

Out[111]= {-1 + p1 + 2 p2}` (2) Please in future include Mathematica input for the expressions of interest.

Comment: Thanks! So now my question is, how would I go about finding p1 and p2?

Comment: I do not understand the question. As used in my n=remark, they are just new variables equated to each of the respective two input expressions. The `GroebnerBasis` use then finds how they are algebraically related.

Comment: I want to express `(3*x + y - z)/(6*x)` and `(3*x - y + z)/(12*x)` only as a function of a new parameter called `p`, where `p` depends on `x,y,z`. I want a way to find this `p`.

Comment: Right. And my `p1` can serve as that `p`. The result I gave shows that if we call the first expression `p1`, then the second expression, `p2`, is equal to `(1-p1).2`, That's what that `GroebnerBasis` indicates. One can of course then use `Solve` to give this value, as in `In[570]:= Solve[
 First[GroebnerBasis[polys, {p1, p2}, {x, y, z}]] == 0, p2]

Out[570]= {{p2 -> (1 - p1)/2}}`

Comment: Okay I see. So if we have a system of 6 equations called ```p1,p2,...```, and after using the ```s=GroebnerBasis[polys, {p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6}, {x, y, z}]``` we get an array of ways the p's are related like ```p5=(1-2*p6)/2```. But for there to be a p, called ```ps```, that ALL p's can be expressed as, that ```ps``` most be mentioned in all elements of ```t=Solve[s[[1]] == 0 && s[[2]] == 0 && s[[3]] == 0 && s[[4]] == 0 && s[[5]] == 0, {p1, p2, p3, p4, p5}]```, right? Then ```Length[polys]-Length[t]``` is then how many different p's you need to express everything in! I think i get it

Comment: That looks mostly correct. Except the `Length[t]` part does not necessarily relate to how many `p` values are needed. What you could try is `Solve[s==0,{p1,...,p6}]` and see if any solution components use only one p_j as "parameter" in terms of which all others are solved. There will be a `Solve::svars` message issued along the way (and you want that).